# Disabling SSL mode to AzureSQL

Tags: azure-sql-database

Is it possible to disable SSL/TLS on connections to AzureSQL? I have a driver which cannot handle SSL.

I know it is a terrible idea BTW since the traffic would then be open to snooping around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done. Azure SQL DB will not accept a non-secure connection. There's no configuration parameter you can set to change this behavior. This is documented in multiple places (e.g. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh351833.aspx). Also, it's not just about the traffic getting sniffed. Azure requires certificate validation also to protect against mitm attacks. Without these, the risk includes credential theft, not just snooping of your traffic.

Btw, what driver are you using? I'm surprised there are drivers that support Azure SQL DB but cannot do it with a secure connection (it's actually TLS, SSL has long been disabled). If you provide more details, folks here might have alternate solutions for your unsafe driver.